# Browser not loading my java-script file from html page

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, web

I am newbie in we designing , i  downloaded a website from github with full source code , when i open my index.html it is not loading the .js file inside in it .please help me, i just opened the index.html file using chrome and Firefox

```
<!doctype html>
        <html lang="en">
         <head>
          <meta charset="utf-8">
          <base href="/">
         <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">

      <title>SHOP</title>
      <meta name="description" content="Polymer Shop Demo">

      <link rel="shortcut icon" sizes="32x32" href="images/shop-icon-32.png">
      <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary">
      <meta name="twitter:site" content="@Polymer">
      <meta property="og:type" content="website">
      <meta property="og:site_name" content="SHOP">
      <meta name="theme-color" content="#fff">
      <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">

      <style>

        body {
          margin: 0;
          font-family: 'Roboto', 'Noto', sans-serif;
          font-size: 13px;
          line-height: 1.5;
          min-height: 100vh;
        }

        /* styling for render while resources are loading */
        shop-app[unresolved] {
          display: block;
          min-height: 101vh;
          line-height: 68px;
          text-align: center;
          font-size: 16px;
          font-weight: 600;
          letter-spacing: 0.3em;
          color: #202020;
          padding: 0 16px;
          overflow: visible;
        }

      </style>

    </head>
    <body>

      <shop-app unresolved>SHOP</shop-app>

      <script src="node_modules/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-loader.js"></script>
      <script type="module" src="src/shop-app.js"></script>

      <script>
        window.performance && performance.mark && performance.mark('index.html');
      </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Are there any errors in the console? Could you please post a reproducible example?

Comment: this is the clone code of git https://github.com/Polymer/shop.git @Edric

Comment: And are there any _errors_ in the console?

Comment: u mean in code? no i guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as though you need the `webcomponents-loader.js` file. If you did not make this with node.js (you can learn it [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U8XF6AFGqlc)), you will need to find that file yourself, or install node.js.

**The following instructions will not help you learn how this works. I would HIGHLY recommend you watch the video link above to learn about node.js before you follow these instructions.**

If you have a folder on your computer with the HTML and JS files (and node.js on your computer) you can open a terminal on your computer, navigate to that folder in the terminal (cd folder_name etc...), and run `npm init` or `sudo npm init`, whichever works.

Then to get a hold of that file, you will need to run `npm i webcomponents.js` to install `webcomponents.js`. Then if you open the folder with the HTML and JS files in a code editor, you should be able to see a folder called node_modules.

In that folder you can find `webcomponentsjs` and under that, there is `webcomponents-loader.js`. You can copy that file and paste it where the main JavaScript file is. Then change the script code to `<script src="src/webcomponents-loader.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="node_modules/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-loader.js"></script>
```

This part says that you need to install the node.js & npm and run it. I recomend you to search what "npm" is.

Comment: how can i install js & npm

Comment: After installing Node.js and NPM from nodejs.org you should run "npm i" in console to install all of the dependencies to the node_modules folder.

Comment: You can also use it to run your applications backend in the future if you so desire.

Comment: hello , i installed Node.js , can you tell me what to do next?

Comment: https://github.com/Polymer/shop#setup here the author described the necessary steps.

Comment: After all instalation is finished open your browser at http://localhost:8081/ If nothing  is displayed or is displayed with errors - let me know.